# A problem of continuity at an endpoint

Tags: continuity, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\alpha>0$ and $1\leq p \leq \infty$.

We define a weighted Sobolev space $$X^{\alpha,p}(0,1):= \{u\in W_{loc}^{1,p}(0,1):u\in L^p(0,1), x^\alpha u'\in L^p(0,1)\},$$ where the notation $u\in W_{loc}^{1,p}(0,1)$ means that $u\in W^{1,p}(V)$ for all compact subsets $V$ of $(0,1)$.

I know $u$ is absolutely continuous on $V$ for all compact subsets $V$ of $(0,1).$ But I am not sure how to establish the continuity of $u$ at the right endpoint $x=1$.

In the case that $0<\alpha<1/2,$ $u$ is continuous at $x=0$ as well, for which I do not know how to prove as well.

My question is how to establish the continuity of $u$ at $x=1$ (and at $x=0$ when $0<\alpha<1/2$).

All help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If $u \in X$, then the restriction of $u$ to an interval $(1/2,1)$ is in $W^{1,p}(1/2,1)$, hence it is continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @daw Yea, thanks for your comment. I figured out the case at $x=0$ when $0<\alpha<1/p$ as well. The condition that $0<\alpha<1/2$ in my post shall be changed into $0<\alpha<1/p$. Let me wrap it into an answer.